# Two different meshes one 3d plot

Tags: plotting

I want to plot two surfaces using Plot3D with a different mesh option, "None" for the first surface and "Full" for the second one, something like this

```
Plot3D[{x^2 + y^2, x + y}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Red, None}, Mesh->{Full,None}]
```

But it does not work, the Mesh option fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create separate plots with desired mesh options and combine them with `Show`:

```
Show[
 MapThread[Plot3D[#, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> #2, Mesh -> #3] &, 
   {{x^2 + y^2, x + y}, {Red, None}, {Full, None}}], 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]